# putting a different background image on a different page in a website

Tags: python, html, css, django

Hello so I am using django templating to make a website. So far only the home page has a background image and I want to place a different image on a separate page. Django templating has me use "extends base html". I keep trying to insert a different background page to replace the generic white background page on the search_results.html but the code doesn't work. I want my search_results.html have a different background from home.html. Appreciate the help!

Code: I'll only include the ones on the head of each html to ensure not too much code about the body is put

**Base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
            My Site
        {% endblock title %}
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{% static 'css/signinform.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add your custom CSS to this file -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

{% block additional_styles %}
 <style>
     body {background-image: url(./static/images/golden_gate_bridge.jpg);
}
    </style>
{% endblock %}

</head>
```

**Home.html (this one uses the image from base.html which is correct)**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block additional_styles %}
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(./static/images/golden_gate_bridge.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

**search_results.html (needs background change!)**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Search Results
{% endblock title %}

{% block additional_styles %}
<style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

This option, which uses a `CSS` [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), allows you keep things structured as is. You would override the custom property (set in your root, shared `CSS` file) each individual page, within your `<style>` block.

**root.css**

```css
:root {
  /* Define this in your global CSS */
  --bg-url: './static/images/golden_gate_bridge.jpg';
}

body {
  background-image: url(var(--bg-url);
}
```

Now, whenever you update `--bg-url`, you update the background dynamically.

**search_results.html**

```css
<style>
  /* Override default background image */
  body {
    --bg-url: './static/images/search_results_img.jpg';
  }
</style>
```

And again for **other_page.html**:

```css
<style>
  /* Override default background image */
  body {
    --bg-url: './static/images/other_page_img.jpg';
  }
</style>
```

### Option 2

Somewhere in your layout, you're including a `body` tag. I would include the page name there and style the backgrounds from a global file.

```
<body class="home">…</body>
```

And:

```
<body class="search-results">…</body>
```

Then, adjust your `CSS` accordingly:

```css
/* base */
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}

.home {
  background-image: url(./static/images/golden_gate_bridge.jpg);
}

.search-results {
  background-image: url(./static/images/search-image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: I prefer option 2.